# While loop not working properly when condition is met

Tags: python, while-loop, append

I am trying to append items to a list, and when I type the word "quit" the loop should stop, and then print the items I have on my list, but the loop continues and still asks me the second question on the loop, which I think should not be happening.

```
itemName = ''
itemPrice = '0.0'
while itemName != 'quit'.lower().strip():
    itemName = input('What item would you like to add?')
    items.append(itemName + ' $' + itemPrice)
    itemPrice = input(f'What is the price of {itemName}?')
for item in items[:-1]:
    print(item)
```

Comment: I put that in the case that someone types the word "quit" with spaces or lower case.

Comment: It seems like you expect the loop to stop immediately when someone types "quit", but that's not how it works.  Without a `break` or `continue` statement, the entire loop body will execute.

Comment: But you're calling `.lower().strip()` on the literal string `'quit'`, which is useless because it's obviously already lowercase and stripped.

Answer (score 4):

I see one problem, you have your `.lower().strip` on the wrong side.
Also, I would suggest using `break` so that your code won't ask for a price if quit is inputted.

```py
items=[]
itemName = ''
itemPrice = '0.0'
while True:
    itemName = input('What item would you like to add?')
    if itemName.lower().strip() == 'quit':
      break
    items.append(itemName + ' $' + itemPrice)
    itemPrice = input(f'What is the price of {itemName}?')
for item in items[:-1]:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code only checks if you wrote quit after it asks both questions. Also, you should put your `.lower().strip()` after the `input()` function. Your code always lowercases and strips the string `'quit'`. You can put an `if` statement after the first question with a break to prevent your code from asking you the second question after you typed `'quit'` for the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to study this.

```
items = []  # storage
totalPrice = 0.0

while True:
    itemName = input('What item would you like to add? ')
    if itemName.lower() == 'quit':
        break

    itemPrice = input(f'What is the price of {itemName}? ')  # ask the price before saving the item
    if itemPrice.lower() == 'quit':
        break

    totalPrice += float(itemPrice)  # convert str to float
    items.append(f'{itemName} $ {itemPrice}')  # Save to storage


print('items:')
for item in items:
    print(item)

print()
print(f'total price: $ {totalPrice}')
```

##### Output

```
What item would you like to add? shoes
What is the price of shoes? 600.75
What item would you like to add? bag
What is the price of bag? 120.99
What item would you like to add? quit
items:
shoes $ 600.75
bag $ 120.99

total price: $ 721.74
```